# Any limit (file size or Floor Area or number of levels) we can load and visualize on Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

So that it does not slow down the BIM loading substantially (say > 2 mins) on the web browser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any limit on those things, but a larger building model requires more computer memories used by your web browser where you opened the Forge Viewer app.

Meanwhile, you may check out our new viewer file format [SVF2](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format). It aids in bringing better performance. In addition, Forge is a cloud platform that your network environment will influence the performance, too.